# Time complexity to fill some part of MxN matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm not good at calculate complexity for an algorithm. Time complexity to fill a MxN matrix is O(MN). Yes I understand that because NxM is the number how much the cell is filled. I know we can calculate best case, average case and worst case.

For example this 4x4 matrix. We only fill the diagonal (D) and one diagonal upside dan downside main diagonal (x). I know the complexity is O(3M-2) thus we have 3.4-2 = 10.

```
|D  x        |
|x  D   x    |
|   x   D   x|
|       x   D|
```

But I can't explain in detail how I can get 3M-2. I just use my imagination with trial and error. That is my best case, if N=M. For the worst case, we have to fill first main diagonal (D1), second main diagonal (D2), cell between D1 and D2 (D) and one cell upside and downside main diagonal (x). All I know, the complexity is O(2*M +(M-N-1)*N + 2*(N-1))

Where M = 9 (max [row,col]) and N = 6 (min [row,col]). See the example below

```
|D1 D   D   D2  x                 |
|x  D1  D   D   D2  x             |
|   x   D1  D   D   D2  x         |
|       x   D1  D   D   D2  x     |
|           x   D1  D   D   D2  x |
|               x   D1  D   D   D2|
```

The area that filled is = 2*9 + (9-6-1)*6 + 2*(6-1) = 34.

2*M represent D1 and D2.

(M-N-1)*N represent D.

2*(N-1) represent x

But I don't know how to write this mathematically. I mean how to describes structurally? I just want to calculate the complexity to fill some part of the matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In each 'full' diagonal you have N elements.
There are M-N+1 full diagonals, because the diagonal which starts at (1,1) ends at (N,N), but the last row has M elements in the last row.

The you want to add the upside and downside diagonals, each of which has (N-1) elements. Thus your complexity is:

```
O(N(M-N+1) + 2(N-1)) = O(NM - NN + N + 2N - 2) = O(NM-NN+3N) = O(N(M-N+3))
```